# Material Design: How to make statusBar and navigationBar translucent programmatically?

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I want this to be done in a fragment. So when the fragment resumes, `statusBar` and `navigationBar` will be translucent and content will overlay. And in onPause, statusBar and navigationBar both will be solid and content won't overlay.

I searched a lot on stackoverflow but didn't find the complete answer. All I got was "How to make statusBar translucent". This is the code:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

NOTE: The above code works fine with statusBar but I also need to do this for navigationBar. And in onPause, I want both of them to be solid.

Example screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nk2B.jpg (Musixmatch)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this:-

In /values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<resources>
<style name=”Theme.TransparencyDemo” parent=”@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light”/>
</resources>
```

Then

/values-v19/styles.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<resources>
<style name=”Theme.TransparencyDemo” parent=”@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light”>
<item name=”android:windowTranslucentStatus”>true</item>
<item name=”android:windowTranslucentNavigation”>true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

In manifest.xml

```
<application android:label=”@string/app_name”
android:icon=”@drawable/ic_launcher”
android:theme=”@style/Theme.TransparencyDemo”>
```

Got from here https://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/

For programatically:-

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
// Holo light action bar color is #DDDDDD
int actionBarColor = Color.parseColor(“#DDDDDD”);
tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(actionBarColor);
}
```

Comment: But I want to do this programmatically and it's for just one fragment not for activity where I can set themes...

Comment: "when the fragment resumes, statusBar and navigationBar will be translucent and content will overlay. And in onPause, statusBar and navigationBar both will be solid and content won't overlay.".

Comment: Also, the article was written in Jan 2014, before Material design was announced. Hence, it's not the solution :/